# Removing handling newlines in a simple text import class

Tags: vb.net

I have an input file that I want to use the string SPLIT function on for each line, depending on the Type field. However, the description field sometimes has data that has new lines in it so it messes up my file reader since it uses streamreader's readline() function

Handled:

> Type|Name|User|Description
>
> Type|Name|User|Description

Unhandled:

> Type|Name|User|Description line 1
>
> Description Line 2
>
> Type|Name|User|Description

Besides not being able to validate on 'Type' for each line and keep reading the file for when the next Type field appears, are there any ways folks can come up with to properly read this file?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to have the file maker replace newline characters in their description field with another unique character that I can later add back in. I'm still interested in solutions from the file reader's perspective though

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm talking to myself a lot here, but I found another solution, which is to remove remove line feeds, since the output file creator wrote out carriage returns for each line.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily set a conditional statement to see if the Split array contains more than one element, which would indicate that it's a line you want to parse.